# Using next() x number of times with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iterator, jquery-selectors

What's an easy way to iterate x number of times using `next()` (applying the same function each time)?

I am working in Sharepoint and have limited control of the HTML; what I can do is find an element by its ID, track down the closest `<td>`, `hide()` it, and then move on to the next one (I don't want all the `<td>`'s, just about 7 or 8 in a row).

The code below works but it's not that pretty.

```
$("#my-easily-identifiable-id").closest("td").hide();
$("#my-easily-identifiable-id").closest("td").next().hide();
$("#my-easily-identifiable-id").closest("td").next().next().hide();
$("#my-easily-identifiable-id").closest("td").next().next().next().hide();
[ ... etc ... ]
```

What's a better way to do this?

Thanks

PS: added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thornomad/Fw49f/) (genius)

Comment: Can you post some sample html that this would be working on (in a fiddle)?

Comment: check out http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: @MichaelHaren I've been away too long - I didn't even know about fiddle! That is amazing.  Posted and updated my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) + [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) with [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

```
$("#my-easily-identifiable-id").closest("td").nextAll().andSelf().slice(0, 7);
```

Answer (score 6):

I think a simpler solution than those posted so far would be [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
//to get next 8 elements
var i = $('#my-easily-identifiable-id').index();
$('#my-easily-identifiable-id').closest('td').nextUntil('', ':lt(' + (i+8) + ')');

//to get self and next 3
var i = $('#my-easily-identifiable-id').index();
$('#my-easily-identifiable-id').closest('td').nextUntil('', ':lt(' + (i+3) + ')').andSelf();
```

Grabs all "next" elements until the filter is hit (in this case we choose the next 8 elements). Verified by [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sP6Gb/2/).

Comment: There's definitely fewer methods involved, but I'm not sure I'd call it simpler. +1 anyway

Comment: Similar to some of the other answers, you're not including the current element, which the original code is.  Also, probably as a result of the fiddle, you're not using `closest("td")` as the original is.

Comment: @James, the second example does include the current element (see `.andSelf()`) and this technique will work with the selected element, or the closest 'td' or any other selected element; updated the post

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it, but perhaps the following might work (I'll test momentarily):

```
$("#my-easily-identifiable-id").siblings().slice($(this).index(),($(this).index() + 8)).hide();
```

Tested and verified with a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sP6Gb/).

Comment: `.slice` is one of those jQuery functions that almost never gets used, but is mighty useful when you need it.

Comment: You've lost the `.closest("td")` and also need to include the original `td`, not just its siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$("#my-easily-identifiable-id").closest("td").hide();
$("#my-easily-identifiable-id").closest("td").nextAll().hide();
```